# NSImage is 'retained' between drag operations

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

Hi I have implemented:

```
- (NSImage *)dragImageForRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)dragRows tableColumns:(NSArray *)tableColumns event:(NSEvent *)dragEvent offset:(NSPointPointer)dragImageOffset
{
    NSImage *dragImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Drag-Icon.png"];
    NSInteger numberOfItems = dragRows.count;
    NSAttributedString *numbers = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",numberOfItems] attributes:attributes];
    [dragImage lockFocus];
    NSRect numbersSurroundRect = NSMakeRect(dragImage.size.width - (numbers.size.width + 15) - strokeWidth - 5, strokeWidth, numbers.size.width + 15, boxHeight);
    NSBezierPath *circle = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:numbersSurroundRect xRadius:9.0 yRadius:9.0];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [circle fill];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    [circle setLineWidth:strokeWidth];
    [circle stroke];
    numbersSurroundRect.origin.y += ((numbersSurroundRect.size.height - numbers.size.height) + 1.75);
    [numbers drawInRect:numbersSurroundRect];
    [dragImage unlockFocus];
    return dragImage;
}
```

In my NSTableView sub-class and when I drag a number of rows in my table I get:

[image]

Then when I drag only 1 or two rows, I get:

[image]

It appears that the old row count is returned and then the new count drawn on top of it....

Could anyone shed any light on this, please? Is it a result of using ARC in my project and somehow the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing directly onto the original image.  You should make a copy before you draw on it so you can draw on a fresh copy the next time.

Comment: Thanks Ken, simply adding NSImage *originalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Drag-Icon.png"]; NSImage *dragImage = [originalImage copy]; worked. So, -lockFocus actually locks to the underlying file? Or at least a 'scratchpad' version of it?

Comment: Yes. +[NSImage imageNamed:] is apparently grabbing the image from the file only the first time and then it caches it and returns the same NSImage on subsequent calls.